# Crashing of a Cloud Functions HTTP Trigger

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have written a HTTP trigger that takes the ECG database name and record no as the arguments and reads the record from the Cloud Storage, calculates the parameters and writes them to Firestore. I observed a very strange thing, the code crashes without indicating the reason in the console. This is all I get in the console:

> Function execution took 58017 ms, finished with status: 'crash'`.

It generally stops when it reads the record from the Cloud Storage. I am using MIT-BIH Cloud Storage to read the records.

```
from google.cloud import storage
from flask import escape
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import numpy as np
import os
from pathlib import Path
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from random import randint

def GCFname(request):
    recordno = request.args['recordno']
    database = request.args['database']

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket_name')

    # it crashes here
    record = wfdb.rdrecord(recordno, channels=[0],pb_dir='mitdb')
    sig = record.p_signal[:,0] 
    test_qrs = processing.gqrs_detect(record.p_signal[:,0], fs=record.fs)

    ann_test= wfdb.rdann(recordno, 'atr',pb_dir='mitdb')

    ##Calculate Parameters

    cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'projectId': 'project_name',
    })

    db = firestore.client()

    doc_ref = db.collection('xyz').document(database).collection('abc').document(recordno)
doc_ref.set({
    u'fieldname': fieldvalue
  })
```

I have deployed using `gcloud`,
`gcloud functions deploy GCFname --runtime python37 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --timeout 540s`

But on using the same URL after some time it works. What could be reason for this? Its definitely not timeout issue.

Comment: This occurs when the HTTP request is triggered repeatedly in a short interval of time. The same thing happens when I am using a Cloud Storage trigger function. It does not give a timeout error. Could it be that the script has timed out internally?

Answer (score 2):

It would be difficult to see why the Cloud Function is crashing without the logs as it can be due to many reasons. Currently, there is a bug open for Cloud Functions crashing before flushing log entries or writing any error trace to Stackdriver. You can follow this issue tracker here for any updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/155215191